# Translate Function Signature to Function (AVL Tree)

Tags: c++, tree, signature, avl-tree

We've been given an assignment to help us prepare to build an AVL Tree. The assignment involves "function signatures." After some Googling, I'm still uneasy on my ability to translate the signatures to actual implementation.

---

**Assignment:**

**1.** Write a recursive routine to calculate the height of a tree. Here is the function signature for the routine that I wrote.

`int AVL<Item_Type>::get_height(AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root)`

Assume the caller invokes this routine as follows:

`get_height(root);`

**2.** Write a recursive routine to delete the nodes in a tree. Use this function signature.

`void delete_tree (AVLNode<Item_Type>*& local_root);`

Think about the three kinds of tree traversals we talked about (pre-order, in-order, post-order). Consider which one is most appropriate for this problem.

Assume the caller invokes this routine as follows:

`delete_tree(root);`

---

**My Implementation:**

**1.**

```
int AVL<Item_Type>::get_height(AVLNode<Item_Type>* &local_root){
int height = 0;

if (local_root == NULL)
{
return -1;
}

int leftHeight = get_height(local_root->left);
int rightHeight = get_height(local_root->right);
int maxHeight = max(leftHight, rightHeight) + 1;
return maxHeight;
}
```

**2.**

```
void AVL<Item_Type>::delete_tree(AVLNode<Item_Type>* &local_root){
if (local_root != NULL){
delete_tree(local_root->left);
delete_tree(local_root->right);
delete local_root;
}
local_root = NULL;
}
// This is post-order tree traversal (<-?)
```

---

How should my functions look? Did I implement them correctly? Point out any other errors you see

Comment: I would have the height of an empty tree be 0, but otherwise your only problem seems to be a lack of indentation (and confidence).  The signature you were given for `get_height` is questionable - the parameter should be `const`, as should the function itself - but that's not your fault.

Comment: @molbdnilo Alrighty, thanks for the post. in this case, the start of my function looks just like their function signature, then. Their delete signature didn't include AVL<Item_Type>:: so that threw me off. Almost every assignment in this class has a typo Or they use the completely wrong term for things so that's another reason I posted.

Comment: And does my delete function use post order tree traversal?

Comment: Yes, you're on the completely right track. I think you will do well in the future.

Comment: @molbdnilo Aw, Thank you! I wasn't fishing for compliments, but I won't complain when I get 'em! :] Thanks for your help